# Use foreach (smarty) with bidimensional array

Tags: php, smarty

i've a bidimensional array and i'm using the construct foreach in smarty.
I've put 6 to the loop of the second foreach nested because i know the number of array's column, but i would put the loop more generally like the first foreach loop where the number of rows is got by array1, how can i do?

```
 {section name=customer loop=$array1}

 {section name=contact loop=6}  
 {$array1[customer][contact]}
 {/section}
 <p>
 {/section}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below format. The `loop` attribute can be an `array` of values or an `integer` representing the number of times to loop.

```smarty
{section name=customer loop=$array1}
  {section name=contact loop=$array1[customer]}  
    {$array1[customer][contact]}
  {/section}
{/section}
```